# Export JSON to Excel using EmberJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a JSON object being returned by the service. I want to export that to a xls or excel file on the click of a button.

When I make a get service call the server return with this:

```
"objects": [
{
  "amount": 1000,
  "date": "2015-12-08",
  "description": "sdadas",
  "from_id": "Prateek",
  "id": 1,
  "to_id": "Prateek,Srabani,Jimmy"
},
{
  "amount": 132,
  "date": "2015-12-08",
  "description": "sdadas",
  "from_id": "Prateek",
  "id": 3,
  "to_id": "Jimmy"
},
{
  "amount": 3000,
  "date": "2015-12-08",
  "description": "asdsasa",
  "from_id": "Srabani",
  "id": 4,
  "to_id": "Prateek,Srabani,Jimmy"
},
{
  "amount": 2000,
  "date": "2015-12-08",
  "description": "asdsasa",
  "from_id": "Jimmy",
  "id": 5,
  "to_id": "Prateek,Srabani,Jimmy"
},
{
  "amount": 100,
  "date": "2015-12-08",
  "description": "adas",
  "from_id": "Srabani",
  "id": 6,
  "to_id": "Prateek"
}
]
```

Apart from this there is no filtering done whatsoever in the front end. I have to export this array of objects to excel with the keys being label of the columns and the values being corresponding rows.

Can someone help me with the handlebars as well as controller code ?

Comment: The question is really too broad at this time. Should be edited to show some code you have attempted and narrow the question to a more specific issue.

Comment: Is the JSON object to be exported somehow filtered or modified in the browser? If it is exported as is you may want to consider generating the file on the server instead of the approach that you have proposed.

Comment: @OrenHizkiya Have edited the question. Now does it make more sense ?

Comment: @paisanco Have edited the question. Now does it make more sense

Comment: You don't “export json to excel”. Have the server generate an excel-recognized format (xls, opendocument, csv, …)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code to export a JSON object to a Excel supported format. Works well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var data = $('#txt').val();
        if(data == '')
            return;

    JSONToCSVConvertor(data, "Vehicle Report", true);
});
});

function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
//If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
    var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

    var CSV = '';    
    //Set Report title in first row or line

    CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

    //This condition will generate the Label/Header
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";

    //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
    for (var index in arrData[0]) {

        //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
        row += index + ',';
    }

    row = row.slice(0, -1);

    //append Label row with line break
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    //1st loop is to extract each row
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";

    //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
    for (var index in arrData[i]) {
        row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
    }

    row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

    //add a line break after each row
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    if (CSV == '') {        
        alert("Invalid data");
        return;
    }   

    //Generate a file name
    var fileName = "MyReport_";
    //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g,"_");   

    //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

    // Now the little tricky part.
    // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
    // but this will not work in some browsers
    // or you will not get the correct file extension    

    //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.href = uri;

    //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".csv";

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
```